# How do I access element attributes with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the HTML code. Now from the HTML using python i need to get just the " style = "width=".

The code I have written is:

`product_item.find_all("span", class_="rating-content" "style" == "width:")`

This is just a one line from the code.

Comment: results = []
for product_item in product_items:
    row = [product_item['data-id'],
           product_item['data-seller-product-id'],
           product_item['data-title'],
           product_item['data-price'],
           product_item['data-brand'], #new
           product_item.i['class'][0], #'tikicon' means TIKI_NOW
           product_item.img['src'],
           product_item.find_all("span", class_="rating-content" "style" == "width:"),
             ]
    results.append(row)
results

Comment: i need to get just Style = Width: from the Class Rating-content. the class = rating-content has many tags under its group. i need to get just Style = width under that Class

Comment: New to coding.. anyone help

Comment: Please edit your question and format it correctly. Put the code you posted in the comments there, now it's hard to read and unclear what you're asking. Don't forget to use the code-formatting button when you edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the Python HTML parsing library [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

From reading its docs, I think you access attributes by using the attribute name as a key on the returned element(s):

```py
product_items = product_item.find_all("span", class_="rating-content" "style" == "width:")

for item in product_items:
  print(item['width'])
```